# Heroku database: How can I view my table entries in deployed herokuapp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to know is their a way to look into our data entries which is made to the **postgresql** database present in **Heroku**. I am using Rails 4 and I have tried `heroku run rails console` it works fine, but everything is all messed up.

And while using `heroku pg:psql` as it was suggested to me as an answer below

**psql is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable file or batch file**

What is wrong with it?. thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the solution to this problem is to move to that specific path where the **psql.exe** is present. For example, `C:\Program Files\PosrtgreSQL\9.3\bin` and  then it can be executed by the following:

```
heroku pg:psql --app app_name
```

this will get this working.

Answer (score 2):

You must (according to [heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-psql)) **have PostgreSQL installed on your system** to use

`heroku pg:psql`

The docs has links to installers for common platforms.

I am using Windows and this fixed the problem for me once I [permanently added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows) the location of `psql.exe` to my system path :

`setx path "%path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin"`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to open the Postgre terminal? If so, just type:

```
Heroku pg:psql
```

In your terminal to enter your database. Docs [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-psql).

Comment: i got an error saying "psql is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable file or batch file".